# Descargar o guardar archivo en el cliente desde ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**En ASP.NET con el lenguaje C#.**

Necesito de alguna manera hacer que mi aplicación descargue o preferiblemente que guarde en el lado del cliente un XML que se genera en mi aplicación.

> En otras palabras que en un boton "Descargar" o "Guardar" pueda descargar el XML en su equipo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buen días, aquí te dejo el código de atrás (Code Behind), en la parte del .ASPX debes agregar un botón que diga descarga y al evento click le agregas este código.

```
private void ButtonDescargar_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.AppendHeader("NombreCabecera", "MensajeCabecera");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/tuRuta/TuArchivo.xml"));
    Response.End();
}
```

Además también puedes usar la función en otros eventos, sí lo deseas, no tienes que limitarte a un botón

Comment: Gracias compañero

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte

Comment: Hola, seguí tu ejemplo y me sirvió a la perfección, mi inconveniente pasa cuando quiero descargar dos archivos (pdf y word) con un mismo botón coloco el mismo fragmento de código para ambos casos cambiando el valor del ContentType y me manda una excepción "El servidor no puede establecer el tipo de contenido después de enviar los encabezados HTTP." como podria solucionar esto, me puedes ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Exc" />
</Triggers>
```

---

```
protected void btn_Exc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ruta;
    ruta = Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/DOCUMENTOS_ADJUNTOS/Formato_Programacion/Formato_Programacion.xlsx");
    DescargarDocumento(ruta);
}
private void DescargarDocumento(String ruta)
{
    try
    {
        String prueba;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "xlsx";
        prueba = Path.GetFileName(ruta).ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + prueba);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(ruta);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ControlarExcepcion(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explica como llegaste a esta solución para que sea mejor aceptada tu respuesta

Comment: hace falta explicar la solucion en caso de que no se agregue una prueba ejecutable del lado de sos

Answer (score 1):

Hola esto los hago en un procedimiento que es llamado por un botón, tomo una lista de clientes y la exporto a un xml para así poder después cargarlos, en realidad para hacer una exportación e importación entre sistemas a través de xml´s

```
if (listaClientes.Count>0)
        {
            try
            {
               
                string xml;
                xml = XmlUtilidades.Serializer(typeof(List<Cliente>), listaClientes);
                Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName("clixml.xml")));
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Imagenes/TuArchivo.xml"));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                //ShowMessage("Exportación realizada correctamente.", "Correcto");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

               
            }
            
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage("Debe escoger que Clientes desea Exportar.", "Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade también a la cabecera de la respuesta el siguiente atributo:

```
// Establecer atributos de cabecera
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
string.Format("attachment; filename = \"{0}\"", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(userFileName)));
```

El atributo "Content-Disposition" con valor "attachment" hará más seguro que el navegador interprete la respuesta como un documento adjunto a guardar.

Internet Explorer 11 cargará el xml como un string en una nueva pestaña del navegador si no añades el atributo "attachment".

Comment: Gracias compañero.
Es posible guardar estos archivos en una carpeta temporal y al momento de la descarga se eliminen?

Comment: No, fijate que estás en una aplicación Asp.Net, simplemente no puedes acceder al sistema de carpetas de la máquina cliente desde el navegador. Son restricciones de seguridad. Debes dejar al usuario que decida cómo y dónde guardar el archivo. Igualmente, no podrás eliminar el archivo como comentas.