# descargar un archivo excel desde mi pagina web

Tags: web

inserte este codigo

```
   $fileName = basename('fichero.txt');
    $filePath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\crm/'.$fileName;
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){
        // Define headers
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        
        // Read the file
        readfile($filePath);
        exit;
    }else{
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
```

para poder descargar este archivo el cual creo en una función de escritura de excel, creo el archivo y luego implemento este codigo para descargarlo pero no me funciona, alguna idea

Answer (score 0):

para tu problema, no se que estes utilizando si asp-net o mvc, pero te comparto la siguiente liga: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33305/131935 en este ejemplo usan para descargar archivos xml, tiene un parecido a lo que tu comentas. Espero y te sirva de guía.